# Gas line inside of cabinet

Tags: gas, stove

I'm moving into a new apartment in a few days and I just noticed the gas stove has the gas line running through the side of the cabinet going inside of the cabinet. It's just hanging there. Is that safe? It doesn't look right to me. I hope that picture is good enough that I sent. As you can see it has the knob on top and it has the flexible line on one side and it's on the bottom cabinet right next to the stove where my kids can get into it. You can't even install the shelf in the middle because the gas line is in the way. I'm worried about canned goods, pots and pans moving it around

[image]

Comment: Most plumbing codes and building codes require support (for example a clamp/strap) for horizontal pipe lines every 3 feet for pipe in 1/2”-1” diameters, and every 4 feet for pipe with diameters greater than 1”. Support spacing should be in accordance with applicable plumbing and building codes. Obviously building codes may vary between countries/continents..

Comment: Hi thank you very much for answer that definitely makes sense because it's just hanging there and it doesn't look right I'm going to try and call somebody this morning just waiting for places to open thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safe in the same sense that a bear is safe; don't disturb it and nobody will get hurt.

I would consider that cabinet off-limits to your children; don't store anything in there which they would need. Keep a lock on it so that your kids don't cause a gas leak.

If you must store stuff in there then just don't bump the gas line too often.

---

If on move-in day a big pot happened to bump the yellow line hard enough to cause a gas leak then turn that valve to the off position, leave the building, and call the **gas company** (not landlord) about a gas leak in your kitchen.

This will cause them to come out and inspect everything. Hopefully they force the landlord to properly run a gas line for the stove instead of this nonsense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer unfortunately the cabinet space is very limited here and with four children I definitely need the space

Comment: However I do like your idea about oops accidentally bump the line

Comment: @CindyKahao Well, just make sure that cabinet is only accessible to you. When the inevitable gas leak happens just make sure there are no ignition sources present, avoid turning on or off any lights, and simply leave the building and call the gas company.

Comment: "come out and inspect everything" actually the first thing they would do is lock the meter and tell the landlord to fix the problem.

Comment: I don't think you need to wait for a gas leak to ask the gas company to come and inspect it.

Answer (score 8):

Others will be along shortly to say if that is legal or not.  If it's not legal your landlord will have to fix it.

It looks very sketchy.  At the *absolute* minimum, I would put some sort of strap in place to hold the pipe up.

There's no reason you couldn't put a shelf in with a cutout to allow the flexible pipe to pass through.  (If you make the cutout big enough, you can slide the shelf in without taking the pipe out.)

Once you have a shelf in, you could probably fasten a bit of wood in place between the shelf and the top of cupboard.  If the piece had a cutout in it, it would then secure the pipe.

As to children, you will have to teach them they must *not* disturb the pipe, and this prohibition is in the "do not run into the road because it may kill you" class rather than the "do not hit your mother's leg with a wooden brick because it will vex her" class.

Comment: +1 for "vex your mother". The rest is good, too.

Comment: I have to admit I stole "because it will vex her" ("him" in the original) from Nick Maclaren (nmm1) in uk.d-i-y.  He was the sort of guy that would never change his opinion just because everyone agreed with him - but he would use it as a warning flag that he should revisit his assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

UCC code related gaslines for appliances can be found in [G2422.1.2.3 (411.1.3.3) Prohibited Locations and Penetrations](https://up.codes/viewer/new_jersey/irc-2015/chapter/24/fuel-gas#G2422.1.2.3).

G2422.1.2.4 states that a value needs to be installed ahead of semi-rigid connector, which is the case. The connection is serviceable (not buried), which is good. Rigid piping material was used in passing through the floor/wall, which is good.

Net-net, this looks fine. It's common for a cooktop's gas line to run through cabinetry, which then connects to a flex line and regulator with-in the cabinet.